# Does cloudstack support Citrix Hypervisor 7 and 8?

Tags: citrix, xen, hypervisor, apache-cloudstack

Only XenServer 6.0 and 6.0.2 is mentioned in cloudstack [docs](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/installguide/hypervisor/xenserver.html), does it support the newer version?

Citrix Hypervisor removed non-free feature from free edition since 7.3 [REF](https://www.shapeblue.com/cloudstack-new-xenserver-licensing-model/). Does it means I can use paided features with cloudstack and Citrix Hypervisor 7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [Compatibility Matrix](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/releasenotes/compat.html).

The answer is yes for xenserver 7.